# Prolog csv flight data analysis

Tags: csv, prolog

I'm working on expert system for flight data analysis. 
the flight is a csv file. i would like to:

- save each flight file( Aircraft number, Motor number and flight date)
- define limitations of parameteres (motor and aircraft) in the Knowledge base:
  for example T4(temperature before turbine) shouldn't exceed 650 over 30s.
- save the report file as pdf or html
  the problem is that to analyse the file you should make loops row by row in order to detect anomalies.
  So, how can i do it with prolog? do you any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what implementation you're using. I'm guessing SWI-Prolog.
You can write csv files using csv_write_file or csv//1,2

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=csv//1

based on OP's feedback:

suppose you have some facts:

engine_temp(Time, Temp).

you could just get a list of them with findall

findall(Time-Temp, engine_temp(Time, Temp), List)

This binds List to pairs of form Time-Temp.

To generate HTML, using the SWI-Prolog library

```
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).

:- http_handler('/temps', temp_hdlr, []).

temp_hdlr(_Request) :-
    reply_html_page(title('engine temps'),
          \temp_list
     ).

temp_list -->
    { findall(Time-Temp, engine_temp(Time, Temp), List)   },
   html(ul(\list_body(List))).

list_body([]) --> [].
list_body([Time-Temp | Rest]) -->
    html(tr([td(Time), td(Temp)])),
    list_body(Rest).
```

Hope a) that works, I'm away from dev machine, and b) the html generation boiler plate doesn't look too scary.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using swi prolog but my problem is how to do floops rows by row ( how to get content of specific cell). For example: If T>650 i should use a counter so if duration is over 30s I should report this anomaly